# how to change selected option in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, select, save, vuejs2, vue.js

```
<el-select @change="store(types)" v-model="types" placeholder="Select">
                        <el-option 
                            v-for="t in types"
                            :label="t.name"
                            :value="t"
                            >
                            </el-option>
```

I am saving the selected option to localstorate using the method store:

```
 store(value){

        var name = value.name;
        var selected = localStorage.setItem('plan', name); // String
    },
```

When I refresh the page or get back to this page I would like to have the selected option which was previously selected. How can I do that with VueJS?

Comment: `el-select` is not an standard element, will you introduce this to folks here, Can you create a fiddle of it?

Comment: this is just a custom select using http://element.eleme.io/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the stored values from localStorage and set it up in created() hook

```
created () {
    this.types = localStorage.getItem('plan')
}
```

For more information about hooks,
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: I have only 1 value in the localstorage.. once I store the value how can I use it to make it as a selected option?

Comment: You would do `this.types.push({'name': localStorage.getItem('plan')})` in `created()`.

Comment: Thank you. Once I have this, the question is how do I make it selected automatically next time I open the page. Basically this was the whole problem. I want the stored value in the localstorage to be the selected option to my select next time I open the page.

Comment: If the code is in `created` hook, the code should run automatically next time you open the page.

Comment: it worked this way: `this.types = localStorage.getItem('plan')` Thank you for the help